# How to implement a "hover" like in Gmail attachments?

Tags: css, reactjs

When you hover over a Gmail attachment, the thumbnail disappears in place of the name of the document *as well as a few buttons.*

[image: no-hover-vs-hover]

The above screenshot hides my cursor, but I'm actually specifically hovering over the "Download" icon and yet, the thumbnail is still gone in place of the file name -- this is the part that I am failing to imitate. In my attempt, I am just changing the opacity of the thumbnail (instead of swapping out for the filename) on hover, but once I am hovering over the button itself, I lose the opacity change.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-euclid-utp7i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the Button above the Image, you can create a CSS rule that applies when the button is hovered:

`.btn:hover + a > img {
  background: #b2b2b9;
  opacity: 0.5;
}`

https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-http-zcedi

Comment: Clicked on link and I don't see a download button on hover

Comment: It has the same behavior as the link you provided, where it only appears if you hover over the button

Comment: Yea I noticed that too. That doesn't happen locally for me like it does on CodeSandbox so I just left it in hopes that an answer could still be found. @aprouja1's answer worked for me